# how to groupby and join multiple rows from multiple columns at a time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to know how to groupby a single column and join multiple column strings each row.

Here's an example dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], [1, 1, 2, 2], 
                            ['k', 'l', 'm', 'n']]).T, 
                  columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
print(df)

    a   b   c
0   a   1   k
1   a   1   l
2   b   2   m
3   b   2   n
```

I've tried something like,

```
df.groupby(['b', 'a'])['c'].apply(','.join).reset_index()

    b   a   c
0   1   a   k,l
1   2   b   m,n
```

But that is not my required output,

Desired output:

```
    a   b    c
0   1   a,a  k,l
1   2   b,b  m,n
```

How can I achieve this? I need a scalable solution because I'm dealing with millions of rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need grouping by `b` column only and then if necessary create list of columns for apply function with [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby('b')['a','c'].agg(','.join).reset_index()
#alternative if want join all columns without b
#df1 = df.groupby('b').agg(','.join).reset_index()
print (df1)
   b    a    c
0  1  a,a  k,l
1  2  b,b  m,n
```

Comment: thank you, is it scalable because I'm dealing with huge dataset with millions of rows. Performance is important.

Comment: @user_12 - hmmm, if working with huge data maybe better is use [dask](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/)